# How do I fetch list of in-active subscribers?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

Any query to grab a list of inactive subscribers? I want to list out all subscribers those have received at least 5 emails but did not open any of those 5 emails in past 3 months?

Comment: for starters, how are you tracking who did or didn't open emails?

Comment: Simply going into tracking tab and select particular send emails.

Comment: I believe it can be done by SQL query by using system tables like Send, Job and Open.

Comment: Are you doing this directly in Marketing Cloud? Or from the connected SF Instance?

Comment: Directly from Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right this can be done using [System Data Views](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/), so as per my understanding you have sent 5 emails to same set of subscribers and want to scrub off those who have not opened the email in past 3 months. If you know the name of the Live audience DE that was used for the send we can check the `EventDate` of the opens for those subs.

Sample Query:

```
select 
subscriberkey
from [Live DE name] 
where subscriberkey NOT IN 
(
  select 
  subscriberkey 
  from _open
  where cast(EventDate as date) >= cast (DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) as date) 
  and JobID = <jobid goes here>
)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Anusha, I haven't run the query yet. But just want to confirm if I do not be specific to job ID (for example If I remove the last line which is "JobID = <jobid goes here>" I should still be able to run the query?

Comment: The reason i added the jobid in where condition is to ensure we are fetching the inactive subscriber of the specific send, the same subscriber can be part of another campaign. so if we remove the jobid condition we will be looking at the recent opens for  subscriber irrespective of the campaign, so depends on your criteria. you can find jobid under Tracking > sends> respective Email Name

Comment: So I do not want to be specific to JOB ID's. What my task is simply grab a list of subscribers those have received at least 5 emails in past three months and they never open any single of those emails?

Comment: Okay then you are good to remove that jobid condition, and be sure to use this result of query as exclusion DE in your UI for that campaign.